# Server following GMT time instead of Local Time

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

I have a Java app that runs on a server present in USA. My app has a method which finds difference between local time and another timestamp value which is fetched from the database and I need to check whether this difference is greater than 86400 seconds(1 day). My problem here is, the **server is following GMT**, **I am unable to find the local time in milliseconds**. I tried to find the offset between USA time and GMT Time and then subtract from the System.currentTimeMillis() to find the local time in USA, with the help of following code

```
int Offset_inmillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
int DSTSavings_inmillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDSTSavings();
long localtime_inmillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + DSTSavings_inmillis + Offset_inmillis;
```

But since the server is taking GMT into consideration, the above code is again giving the GMT time value in milliseconds(Both Offset_inmillis, DSTSavings_inmillis values are 0 in the code above). I can provide a work around by subtracting the offset(hardcoding the offset value in the code), but I dont want to do that since, it doesnt take care of daylight savings and the code doesnt work if its hoisted on a different server in a different timezone.

I need solution where the code works for all timezones. For that, I need the solution to find the local time (in milliseconds) of the server(but server is following GMT time in this case). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the difference between local time and another timestamp value which is fetched from the database

```
// Change 'America/New_York' depending on the local timezone of your server
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"); 
// Gives the offset of your server timezone from the GMT
long tzoffset = tz.getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

btw, ideally database timestamp should be in GMT as well

Comment: I have a doubt whether this returns a different value when daylight savings are not being observed. Currently, its returning the correct value. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.TimeZone class to achieve this.There is a small example here this:

```
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/TimeZones.shtml
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I used TimeZone in my code. the problem is not with that. the server following GMT is the main problem